# Log in problem in maintenance mode

Tags: users, maintenance-mode

I have a maintenance site problem. I can't go to the login page.

I tested in my localhost in maintenance and I could log in on /user.

I copied file system and database online but here I can't access the login page so I can not see the site to make changes and upload data.

This is the site: 
[redlily.it/](http://www.redlily.it/)

I have displayed the $content variable in a div.content with display:none style. But in '?q=user' and in '/user' i have no loggin form.

Why am I not seeing the log in form under '?q=user' and '/user'?

Answer (score 1):

You can run below queries on database to get your site online:

```
UPDATE variable SET value = 's:1:"0";' WHERE name= 'site_offline';
DELETE FROM cache WHERE cid = 'variables';
```

Comment: I want to login offline.. I have to edit all the data before go online.. 
I have to correct this "Drupal" link on top of the page too..

Answer (score 0):

in your DB find variable table and change site_offline from 1 to 0

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the database setting.. wrong password -.-

Solved!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Using Apache on Ubuntu.
edited /etc/apache2/apache2.conf changing
AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All for /var/www:

AllowOverride All

Drupal was installed in a sub-directory in /var/www .