# logging in after exiting website under maintenance

Tags: database, configuration

i was installing updates for drupal website, while on maintenace mode. waited for updates to finish and then signed out. i've been trying a lot of things i'm reading online and it doesn't work. on another note, possibly related, when i've tried to do some editing on certain blocks i get the message that i don't have sufficient permission to edit. also, while googling online i found my website, though, with a different url that had the log-in ability, but my credientials didn't work. i believe my next attempt is to insert or edit code in the db..how can i do that? or whats the best solution? sorry to type so much, i've been doing a lot of research on this and i've become desperate.

Comment: See duplicate question here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56677/log-in-problem-in-maintenance-mode

Answer (score 0):

Are you logging in as Admin (user 1) or a site administrator?  They are the only ones who have the rights to login while the site is in maintenance mode.  The URL should be http://www.example.com/user/login or http://www.example.com/index.php?q=user .

KMT

Comment: based on my privileages on the site i take i'm user1. when i've tried to edit certain blocks, it would tell me i can't because of my privileage level. there were other people that were managing the website before i started. i tried both urls..and nothing.

Comment: when you go to the login page at /user/login, do you see the page?

Comment: If you have PHPMyAdmin access to the database, you could try this: http://picxelplay.com/kb/how-put-drupal-offlineonline-database: UPDATE variable SET value = 's:1:"0";' WHERE name= 'site_offline';
DELETE FROM cache WHERE cid = 'variables';

Comment: No, I don't see the page. i ran the code, it says it ran the query successfully. could you now tell me how exactly do i implement the code? am i using Filezilla?